# Trying to create a leaderboard using Firebase backend and sorting data doesn't retrieve data correctly (Swift 4.2)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uikit

Im currently trying to implement a leaderboard in my app using a UITableView and a Firebase Database backend, I need to be able to sort data according to highest score and display the Username and score accordingly. The current code doesn't retrieve data and uses the optional default values that are coded.

```
func retrieveScores(){
    _ = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let highScoreDB = Database.database().reference().child("Leaderboard").child("True False Quiz").queryOrdered(byChild: "High Score")

    highScoreDB.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>
        print(value)

        let userName = value["Name"] as? String ?? "error"
        let highScore = value["High Score"] as? Int ?? 0
        print(highScore)

        let score = HighScore()
        score.name = userName
        score.score = highScore

        self.scoreArray.append(score)
        self.highScoreTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This is the function that retrieves user data and then passes it into an array where the table view can access the data.

The console currently prints:

```
["ZybxNO7fQeMHEkc2CnCq74xsmus1": {
"High Score" = 9;
Name = ty;
}, "kLxqZteRfBeC0bNIkLCjrPukMGx1": {
    "High Score" = 11;
    Name = Sam;
}]
```

which is the data being retrieved from the database, but this data is not appended and the app displays the following:
[App View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKGZM.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you request the result of a query as a value, you get a single snapshot that has all the nodes that match your query. To get to each individual node, you need to loop over the children of that snapshot:

```
highScoreDB.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
  for score in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
    let value = score.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    print(value)

    let userName = value["Name"] as? String ?? "error"
    let highScore = value["High Score"] as? Int ?? 0
    print(highScore)

    let score = HighScore()
    score.name = userName
    score.score = highScore

    self.scoreArray.append(score)
  }
  self.highScoreTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` have other structure than you're waiting for.
Seems like your firebase model looks like

```
{
 <some_key>: {
         "Name": String,
         "High Score": Int
      }
}
```

You're trying now to get "Name" of the `value` you just obtained and you won't reach this until your model has look like now.
Firstly you have to get value for your `key` and **THEN** get your "Name" and "High Score".